# IEnumerable<T> considered harmful?

Tags: c#, collections, resharper

I have inner tension regarding `IEnumerable<T>`.  On the one hand, I understand it is more generic than concrete collection types, such as arrays or lists, and for that reason Resharper is constantly prodding me to change my method parameters from `List<T>` or `T[]` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, whenever I do that, more often than not, I *eventually* (after adding to the code) run into the dreaded `possible multiple enumeration` warning from that very same Resharper.  This forces me to declare another variable, which is often hard to name, just to store the result of a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` call, whose only purpose is to turn something that already was a list or array into another list or array.

What's the best way to resolve this tension (besides uninstalling Resharper lol)?

Comment: `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` ?

Comment: Doesn't help... resharper will still prod me to change it to IEnumerable<T>, as long as the method uses only functionality provided by IEnumerable<T>, since it's the most generic

Comment: `possible multiple enumeration` just indicates that you're iterating over the same collection more than once -- imagine loading the data directly from a database. You'd be doing that twice or even more. In this case fetching all entries with `ToList` is helpful.

Comment: I know but *it's really already a list*.  Resharper just made me declare it as IEnumerable.  I don't really like adding extra code and an extra variable, just to turn a list into a list.  (I think I said this already in the question)

Comment: @JoelFan can you show specific examples where you're getting that R# warning?

Comment: any method with a parameter of type List<T> or T[], where all I do is iterate it with a `for` loop.

Comment: i recommend taking resharpers suggestion as what it is. a _suggestion_, not a law you have to follow. if you think that returning a List instead of IEnumerable is best, then that is the way to go.

Comment: It's not about returning, it's about method parameters

Comment: @JoelFan a minor detail that does not invalidate my opinion on the matter. resharper is just a tool to guide you - but you, as developer, should know best in the end.

Comment: Yeah,`.ToList()` adds at least an array allocation and copy (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L75). Not an ideal situation. Ideally the analysis pass should only trigger if you enumerate once, but false positives are still possible.

Comment: "Resharper just made me declare it as IEnumerable." - resharper didn't *make* you do anything; it voiced an opinion - in my opinion an incorrect one for many cases - and you chose to follow it. If it doesn't meet your scenario: *don't do that*. If resharper is spotting possible multiple enumeration: *then you probably shouldn't be using IEnumerable in that case* - you can always turn down the recommendation from resharper

Comment: I think people are confused by what I'm saying... Step 1: resharper suggests changing List to IEnumerable, because it's more generic.  Step 2: I follow that advice.  Step 3: I *change* the code in the method so that it enumerates the parameter more than once.  Step 4: Reharper complains about that (*not* a false positive, resharper is right).  Step 5: I need to add an extra variable to convert the IEnumerable to a list, even though it really already is one. That is not desirable.

Comment: @JoelFan k; if your point is "resharper shouldn't tell me to do X, if the moment I do X, it is going to tell me off about X" - then yes, that would be great feedback to give to the resharper product folks; but we're not the resharper product folks, so the best we can say is "don't do X, then". You can usually disable/overrule such guidance locally or globally, so it doesn't keep saying the same thing.

Comment: It's not the same moment.... it's later on after I add code that enumerates the parameter more than once.... so it's not `guaranteed` that I'll get into that situation... it just seems like it happens a lot...

Comment: @JoelFan well, if you *changed* what you were doing: it makes sense that the guidance related to that will change; there are very good reasons to only enumerate an enumerable once - technically they aren't guaranteed to be repeatable: it might *only be possible* to enumerate once, so: the guidance is good here; but feel free to disregard any and all such advice from **any** automated tool, if you know more from the specific / usage (just: maybe add a comment explaining why you're overruling it, because you might not remember in 6 months when you next read it)

Comment: OK but following the guidance at the beginning, when I don't yet know that I'm going to need to enumerate it twice, *often* (not *always*) leads me to the "multiple enumeration" guidance later, which makes me either add unnecessary code or go back and undo the change I made before (changing it to IEnumerable)

Comment: @JoelFan yes: sometimes we need to go back and change code that we've already written, to better reflect recent usage changes; fortunately, most drives aren't read-only

Comment: The problem comes when you're writing a library to be used by a third party. If you declare a parameter as `IEnumerable<T>` and publish your library, you can't then change it to `IList<T>` without potentially breaking third-party code. The solution in that case would be to keep the old method and add a new one which accepts (say) `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and call the new method from the old one by using `Enumerable.ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`. The former adds a `Count`, and the later also adds an indexer. These are almost as general as `IEnumerable<T>`, but avoids the multiple enumeration warning since they *probably* represents an in memory list. And using these interfaces prevents the list from being modified, at least unless the methods messes around with casting.

Comment: OK but R# will still want me to change even those to `IEnumerable<T>`.  It wants the most generic possible

Comment: @JoelFan I can't say this enough times: **you're not required to follow that advice** - you can happily say "oh, cheers resharper, I've considered that and decided that what I have is fine and preferable" - and just add a local rule override